# How to import CSV column as list in Python?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a large CSV with vocabulary words in the first column and definitions in the second. I want to access the values in these CSV columns in my iPython workspace, where I will make the contents of each CSV column into a list.

Let's say my example CSV looks like this:

```
study_list.csv = [
vocabulary,translation
machen,make
gehen,go
geben,give]
```

I'm trying to end up with something like this in iPython:

```
vocabulary = ["machen", "gehen", "geben"]
translation = ["make", "go", "give"]
```

Once these lists are defined in Python, I should be able to do this:

```
print(vocabulary)
>machen, gehen, geben

print(translation)
>make, go, give
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) module? It is difficult to say anything else, because you are not specific about your input and desired output data structure. Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('study_list.csv','r') as csv_file:
    lines = csv_file.readlines()

vocabulary = []
translation = []
for line in lines
    data = line.split(',')
    vocabulary.append(data[0])
    translation.append(data[1])
```

You can create other lists for the other columns like this above the for loop, and append to them inside with the corresponding index.

Answer (score 2):

Matt_G's answer is great for your exact question (e.g. a small, simple CSV), but if you every have larger CSVs or an unknown number of columns, or just want to automate list creation, I recommend a dictionary of lists. The code below will take a CSV file of any shape and import it into a dictionary of lists, with all CSV headers (from line 0 of the file) as the dictionary keys. For example, from your sample CSV: `outputDict['vocabulary']==["machen", "gehen", "geben"]`. The headers from the file can be returned as the dictionary keys with `outputDict.keys()`

```
with open('study_list.csv','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

headers=lines[0].rstrip().split(',')    # rstrip removes end-of-line chars
numLines = len(lines)

linelist = [x.rstrip().split(',') for x in lines[1:numLines+1]]       # create lineList to include only numLines elements
outputDict = {keyVal:[x[idx] for x in linelist if len(x)==len(headers)] for idx,keyVal in enumerate(headers)}    # list comprehension within dictionary comprehension to split each element by its header and create dictionary of lists
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
vocabulary = []
translation = []
with open('study_list.cs', mode='r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')  
    for n, row in enumerate(reader):
        if not n:#skip header
            continue
        vocabulary.append(row[0]) 
        translation.append(row[1])
```

Or you can use

```
import csv
vocabulary = []
translation = []
with open('study_list.cs', mode='r') as f:
     reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')  
     for n, row in enumerate(reader):
         if not n:#skip header
             continue
         vocabulary.append(row['vocabulary']) 
         translation.append(row['translation'])
```